# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list. Error occurs when assigning 2 variables to one variable

Tags: python

I am making a password generator using a class called `password` and a 2 functions called `generate_memorable` (generates a passwords that can be easily remembered) and `generate_intricate` which will generate a complex password.

My Code:

```
import random
import urllib.request
import string

class password:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def generate_intricate(self, iterations):
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        for p in range(iterations):
            output_password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += random.choice(characters)
            print(output_password)

    def generate_memorable(self, iterations):
        # get some random words
        word_url = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
        req = urllib.request.Request(word_url, headers=headers)
        response = response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        long_txt = response.read().decode()
        words = long_txt.splitlines()

        output_password = ''

        # generate the number of password specified
        for i in range(iterations):
            while len(output_password) != self.length:

                # generate a random number with a length of 3 to 5
                for i in range(random.randint(3, 5)):
                    numbers = random.randint(1, 9)

                # the ouput password is equal to the words from the world_url and numbers put together
                output_password = words + numbers # THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS OCCURING

                # im trying to make sure that the length of the generated password is equal to the length specified by the user
                if len(output_password) > self.length: # if length of password is larger than length specified
                    difference = len(output_password) - self.length # difference between output password and length specified
                    print(output_password[: -difference]) # print the output password minus the difference.  

                elif len(output_password) < self.length: # if length of output_password is smaller than length specified
                    difference = self.length - len(output_password) # difference = length specified - length of output_password
                    print(output_password,output_password[: difference]) # print output_password + difference characters from output_password. 

                elif len(output_password) == self.length: # if length of output_password = length specified
                    print(output_password)

# Test
password1 = password(20) # password length = 20
password1.generate_memorable(3) # generate a memeorable password (containing words and numbers) 3 times
```

**My Problem**

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sbenf\OneDrive\Python Projects\Large Projects\Adventure_Colussus_Game\passwordtest.py", line 55, in <module>
    password1.generate_memorable(3) # generate a memeorable password (containing words and numbers) 3 times
  File "C:\Users\sbenf\OneDrive\Python Projects\Large Projects\Adventure_Colussus_Game\passwordtest.py", line 37, in generate_memorable
    output_password = words + numbers # THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS OCCURING
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I have no idea what to do so I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Loop which you execute before line which throw an error is useless, cause you're storing result only of last iteration.

Comment: Note that `numbers` is going to be a single digit. You want to write `numbers = random.randint(100, 99999)`

Comment: `words` is a list, and `numbers` is an integer.  You can't add those two things together using a plus sign.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: I would say that the error is quite clear regarding the issue: `words` is a list (obtained from `long_txt.splitlines()` while `numbers` is an int (obtained from `random.randint(1, 9)`). Either do `words.append(numbers)` or according to the its name, maybe `numbers` should acctually be `numbers = [random.randint(1, 9) for i in range(random.randint(3, 5))]` in which case the addition will work (adding two lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the end goal if for `output_password` to be a string, then you need to join the list of words and append the int (converted to a string) afterwords.

```py
words = ["hello", "world"]
numbers = 123
output_password = "".join(words) + str(numbers)
```

outputs:

```
helloworld123
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a `list` (`words`) to an `int`, even though both types aren't meant to be added. To solve it you must transform the `int` to `list`, with something like

```
output_password = words + [numbers]
```

Another point is: your code isn't producing the numbers of 3 to 5 of length. Since you're just iterating 3 times in the loop `for i in range(random.randint(3, 5)): numbers = random.randint(1, 9)` without saving the result of the random generator, it will always overscript the `numbers` variable. You must first define that `numbers` is an empty list and then append the generated random numbers to it, like this:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(random.randint(3,5)):
    numbers.append(random.randint(1,9))
```

Now that `numbers` is a list, it could be added to `words` without further problems

Comment: It'll just add 1 int to whole content of `long_txt`, which technically avoids error but doesn't fix logic